# Explain this Code?

Tags: java

So I know that this code takes a random 10 number array and puts it in order from lowest to highest. How does it do it though? Can you explain what the loops, the buffers and the I's and J's?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Divisible {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = new int [10];
    //generates 10 Random numbers in the range of 1-20
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        array[i] = (int)(Math.random()*20 + 1);
    }           
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

    int buffer = 0;
    for(int i1 = array.length-1; i1 > 0; i1--) {

        for(int j = 0 ; j < i1 ; j++) { 

            if(array[j] > array[j+1]) {

                buffer = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = buffer;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
}
```

Comment: When you step through this code in a debugger, is there a specific operation which isn't clear?  What specifically don't you understand?  Currently it sounds like you found some code online and you want us to teach you Java so you can understand it.  That's too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why don't you write your own code that you actually understand? This code looks like bubble sort written in a slightly not readable way.

Answer (score 1):

It's bubble sort. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Bubble_sort for explanation.